# How do I decompress multiple files and archives from a zipped file C#

Tags: c#, zip, compression, directoryinfo, c#-ziparchive

I have this code that works great for one archive, but if I have a zipped file that has multiple archives they will not get unzipped.

Here is the code:

```
var directoryPath = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\example\");
Decompress(directoryPath);

public static void Decompress(DirectoryInfo directoryPath)
{
    foreach (FileInfo file in directoryPath.GetFiles())
    {
        var path = directoryPath.FullName;
        string zipPath = path + file.Name;
        string extractPath = Regex.Replace(path + file.Name, ".zip", "");

        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
    }
}
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Recursion: If the file in the zip is a zip re-call the method to extract the zip from the zip.

Comment: Do you mean a "multi-part archive" (a zip file split into multiple files)?

Comment: @Robert no I mean just an archive is multiple archives in of one or more folders